# how to get total of a field in prisma over a relation

Tags: javascript, prisma

I have the following models

```
model admins {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name      String
  last_name String
  phone     String    @unique
  email     String?   @unique
  nic       String?   @unique
  image     String?
  payments  payment[]
}

model payment {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  amount      Int
  description String?
  date        DateTime? @db.Date
  admin_id    Int
  admins      admins    @relation(fields: [admin_id], references: [id])
}
```

And I want to query and get each admin's payment total amount. so I query like this

```
  const data = await prisma.payment.groupBy({
    by: ["admin_id"],
    _sum: {
      amount: true,
    },
  });
  console.log(data);
```

It returns the result as `{ _sum: { amount: 1650 }, admin_id: 1 }` for each admin. what I would like is to include the admin `name` and `last_name` too. I want something like this for each admin.

```
{ 
   _sum: { amount: 1650 },
   admin_id: 1,
   name: "admin-name",
   last_name: "admin-last-name"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, it's not possible to use [include](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#include) or [select](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#select) with groupBy queries.

You can perform a second query to get the name and last_name of each admin. You'd map over the results of your first query and use the admin_id field to get the related admin information.

It could look something like this:

```js
const paymentData = await prisma.payment.groupBy({
  by: ["admin_id"],
  _sum: {
    amount: true,
  },
});

const dataWithAdminInfo = await Promise.all(paymentData.map(async (item) => {
  const admin = await prisma.admins.findUnique({
    where: { id: item.admin_id }
  });

  return {
    ...item,
    name: admin.name,
    last_name: admin.last_name
  };
}));

console.log(dataWithAdminInfo);
```